# how to print column names as well while reading the values for that variable

Tags: linux, awk

I have below sample data

```
EMP_ID|EMP_NAME|AGE|SALARAy
123456|XXXXXXXXX|30|10000000
```

Is there a way I can split the record into multiple records and also get header. Example output should be like

```
EMP_ID|Values|HeaderName
123456|XXXXXXX|EMP_NAME
123456|30|AGE
123456|10000000|SALARY
```

I tried using the below command

```
awk -F\| 'NR>1{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){print $1"|"$(i)}}' records.txt
```

Here I am unable to get the header name and I am getting only EMP_ID & Values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the headers and save it in an array:

```
 NR==1 { for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) h[i]=$i }
```

then you can simply add them using `h[i]`

```
awk -F\| '
    BEGIN { print "EMP_ID|Values|HeaderName" }
    NR==1 { for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) h[i]=$i }
    NR>1 { for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) print $1"|"$i"|"h[i] }
' records.txt
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. Can i specify a rage of attributes here. Currently in the above command i am trying to append ${1}`"|"S{i}. . But instead of only one columns ${1} i have some 10 columns . Is there any  i have specify range and then get all the 10 columns and append the $(i)

Comment: I don't really understand. Please ask a new question and provide some example input and the desired output.

Comment: Hi pLumo.. I have submitted new question

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/519965/specifying-the-range-of-the-arguments-to-print-in-every-record-line