# Specifying the range of the arguments to print in every record line

Tags: linux, awk

We have a sample data as below

```
EMP_ID|EMP_NAME|AGE|SALARAy|DepId|DepName
123456|XXXXXXXXX|30|10000000|1234|XYZWE
```

I have used below code to split the data as below

```
awk -F\| '
BEGIN { print "EMP_ID|Values|HeaderName" }
NR==1 { for(i=3;i<=NF;i++) h[i]=$i }
NR>1 { for(i=3;i<=NF;i++) print $1"|"$2"|"$i"|"h[i] }
' records.txt
```

And Output IS

```
EMP_ID|EMP_NAME|Values|HeaderName
12345|XXXXXXXXX|30|AGE
12345|XXXXXXXXX|10000000|SALARY
12345|XXXXXXXXX|1234|DepID
12345|XXXXXXXXX|XYZWE|DepName
```

In the command i have specified """   print $1"|"$2"|"$i"|"h[i]  """ , Starting first and second column appending with $i and h[i]. Instead of Specifying $1,$2 i have some more columns which results in mentioning as $1"|"$2"|"$3"|"$4 ....

Instead of keeping all the column names sequentially , can i mention any range. I have tried below command but didn't worked.

```
for i in ${@:1:4}
```

Instead of keeping $1"|"$2"|"$3"|"$4..... can i specify any range like 1:4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ awk -F'|' '
    BEGIN {
      getline; split($0,a); OFS=FS; 
      print "EMP_ID", "EMP_NAME", "Values", "HeaderName"
    } 
    {
      for (i=3;i<=NF;i++) print $1, $2, $i, a[i];
    }
' sample
EMP_ID|EMP_NAME|Values|HeaderName
123456|XXXXXXXXX|30|AGE
123456|XXXXXXXXX|10000000|SALARAy
123456|XXXXXXXXX|1234|DepId
123456|XXXXXXXXX|XYZWE|DepName
```

If you want to limit the range of output fields to be the same as the number of header fields, change `split($0,a)` to `n = split($0,a)` and then change the `for` loop termination condition to `i<=n` instead of `i<=NF`. Or change it to a fixed number if that's what you want.

Comment: Hi , Thanks for the reply. Instead of print $1, $2 .... Instead if $1 , $2 can i specify any range , because i have many columns to mention it like $1,$2,$3,$4 .... -- i want to overcome this and mention any range. Do we have any possibility ?

Comment: @Arya please see my edit

Comment: Sorry for repeating the same. I am trying to achieve the condition as below.. 

instead of "    for (i=3;i<=NF;i++) print $1, $2, $i, a[i]; " , can i specify it like                   "   for (i=3;i<=NF;i++) print $1:2 , $i, a[i];

Comment: @Arya AFAIK `awk` does not have such an "array slice" syntax

Answer (score 0):

You can print data from a range of columns with a construct like this :

```
echo {0..9} | awk '{ for(i=3;i<8;i++) {printf $i"|"} }'
```

outputs :

```
2|3|4|5|6|
```

Comment: i am unable to get the output. It shows blank values from 2nd record. As per the above output for all the four records first 2 columns should remain same , but here i am getting blanks from 2nd record.